# Unity - admobs not showing, throwing error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I am trying to show interstitial ads when the player clicks on specific button (hint button), but Unity is giving me this error:

```
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object ButtonManager.Hint()...
```

This is the code for showing the ad:

```cs
public class ButtonManager : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

    public void Home()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }
    int contc;
    public void Play()
    {
       SceneManager.LoadScene("LevelMenu");
    }
    public void Hint()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<AdMobManager>().Hint = true;
        FindObjectOfType<AdMobManager>().showInterstitial();
    }
```

Any idea how can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is a C# error, you are trying to use a null Object.
I think the problem is:
FindObjectOfType()

Check if you really get any object with that Find.

Comment: i have a ``` public bool Hint; ```

Comment: that's not the problem. The problem is the AdMobManager Object, not the bool property inside it. Usually (outside Unity) you will get that problem if you do not initialize your Object ( = new AdMobManager ()), but since this is unity I think it's the FindObjectOfType method that fail to return a AdMobManager GameObject

Comment: so what can i do?

Comment: Try to put that FindObjectOfType<AdMobManager>() in a AdMobManager variable and check if it's null.